# How can I access policy data from my attribute provider?

Tags: java, xacml, pdp, authzforce

I am dealing with AttributeProvider. Needed to implement Attribute Provider that will access another service API. So I have prepared everything according to the [documentation](https://github.com/authzforce/core/wiki/Attribute-Providers#making-an-attribute-provider).

AttributeProvider has been successfully registered and everything works fine. But there is one thing that is not clear. How can I access policy data from my attribute provider?

Comment: What do you mean by "policy data"? Do you mean you want to get the XACML policies from your attribute provider? Attribute providers provide values of attributes used by policies. Policy providers provide the policies.

Comment: Yes, I need to get XACML policy rules/conditions inside my Attribute Provider

Comment: AttributeProviders are not supposed to access the XACML policies, but Policy Providers are. What exactly do you need to do with the policies in your AttributeProvider?